# TypeScript: Override Generic Types in Method<T> that inherit from a Class<T> fallback

Tags: typescript, generics, types

I prepared a simplified example of an Angular Service, that comes with multiple Generic Types that allows overrides via the methods. The problem I face here is `=` vs `extends` and typing within the arguments. For some reason the `=` works perfect for the return types but the argument types need the `extends`.

```js
class Service<
    RequestBody,
    ResponseBody,
    CreateRequestBody = RequestBody,
    CreateResponseBody = ResponseBody,
>
{
    public createOne<
        $CreateRequestBody extends CreateRequestBody,
        $CreateResponseBody = CreateResponseBody
     >(body : $CreateRequestBody) : $CreateResponseBody
    {
        return null;
    }

    public createTwo<
        $CreateRequestBody = CreateRequestBody,
        $CreateResponseBody = CreateResponseBody
    >(body : $CreateRequestBody) : $CreateResponseBody
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here are the examples to reflect the problem, I want to use the `createTwo()` method once I figured out the issue. At this point it does not validate the type for body.

```js
const service: Service<{ foo: string }, void> = new Service<{ foo: string }, void>();

// working
service.createOne({
    foo: 'test'
});

// not fine as the types are not compatible
service.createOne<void, void>({
    bar: 'test'
});

// not fine as everything can be set for body - typing not working for some reason
service.createTwo({
    bar: 'test'
});

// fine as the local override works
service.createTwo<{ bar: 'test' }, void>({
    bar: 'test'
});
```

Here is a [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKCmAnAbgS2PAPAKGn6ASvAI4Cu8EALgEID2AJgJ4A0u+READrQHYTx0mrfNADCieGErwiZCjQaNoAXkIlyVQSzZ5xk6R258BilWq69+W1gD5sAbx3ROpAEYh00YBKnwA8jxYTiIAJHq+shoKTNDwAB7SPPQw4Qbq8tbB+GE+aRbGWmapMhRGVorBNgAUrqYAXNA5+iVymooAlNANTRGlliZMTo4iIhKUpIg80DykICAAhADcTgC+2E4u7p7ezQAqAO60OCPZxZEZpqpn6W1CWXg9eWUDSle5JfnlgyLVtTHd11a0UYnQB70M-S0Q3u0DGEymMzmS1W2DW2GAlko0H4KHQ8AaCFxGEw9mgADNaLQGlREKgeABzaArZjQZC0VD0GxmQL7OBINDE0kUqnYyi0hlMllsjnVdrLbAAegV0EOiAA1nT6dgcQL4AA6Ha+ALwKrDfDChoAcmkVEtqLl6yV01oWLJdPg0Eg0EoAAsPZRGJwKJ6JM6sRiALacKSodzwbX8vEG97GzDS+hS9mc01OVxgRBWm2UO0rB2K5U8F3k92emDwZBIRi+zVeMBTVwe-iu2iIaB-JQAWm9gZblaxqo1EopvYgtAjHp8s54CaJ+sN0gOtBzIjzBeg1vkJbLTrdgVr3r90BAtGAYBA0FoDcQtPoHonEBXuuTe0OJL7+cLQ9JVZLNqjNPBd0A217UWIA) to see what the compiler does.

Comment: Your playground link is corrupted; could you fix it?

Comment: Do you know what `=` is?  It's a [default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults), not a constraint.  I'm not sure what the purpose of all the generic type parameters are here, anyway.  If I remove all but the first two on the class I get [this code](https://tsplay.dev/wenXKN) which seems to work just fine.  That's my suggestion unless you can make the [mre] demonstrate a use case which requires the additional type parameters.

Comment: I fixed the playground link, thanks

Comment: Also note that your example code has errors at `return null`; you should probably remove or suppress those errors so as not to distract from your question.  If you don't care about implementation you could write `return null!` to make it `never`. Or you can do something else.

Comment: Hmm, maybe I'm not getting the point of the "local override"...

Comment: Well, this is part of a CRUD service and I need to override the defaults defined via the class while calling the method / operation.

Comment: So, does [this code](https://tsplay.dev/wg6g0W) meet your needs? I'm not super happy playing games with types like this, especially since I don't see how the implementation could conform to it, but if it works for your use cases I'll write up an answer.  If not, please elaborate on what's missing.

Comment: Thanks for going so far with me. Your example call `service.create({bar: 'test'});` does not invalidate what equals my `service.createTwo({bar: 'test' });` thas is mentioned as the root of the problem.

Comment: Oops, sorry... try [this](https://tsplay.dev/NnXaqW) instead.

Comment: That actual solved the issue in cost of having a third unused type. Can you explain why this "hack" is needed for argument types but not for return types?

Comment: I was like fooling arround with the TypeScript helpers and could hack something together using Omit<type, null>. Can you confirm that? See [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKCmAnAbgS2PAPAJQI4BppsIA+AKAG8zoboAHAVwCMR1phF4wAXLa2gXgDyyJIlQATeAFEAHnVbBU3aAF4iBfgJrYmIsZPhqiEfFu0kAFEwD2EgJ4AuaEIC2ynLn2JxUuQvRlQgA7BhAQEgBKZ11vXyMqbVpObgZEYOhQ8IBCAG5zAF8yMiKyYBtgiBUIJDQMZwQUdCwKaAAzGxtnKvFggHNoAsJkG0kSY2D4AHc4WubMVo6u6B7UfsHh0YkrSPyyGqaMADoOLl5LRNol5wByXiqbkt3ig7r4E84eLBHJTbGL8xMMCIW73biPArPF5zY6nL4AgRAkHQO7wB5PPavZofM4taBI0Fo8EbaA-bYI2gElFgiG7IA).

Comment: I can write up an answer when I get a chance.  I'm not sure what to do when I see a link that has an error in it... you don't want `Omit<T, null>` when `null` is not a valid keylike type.  Maybe `Omit<T, never>` or something like `NoInfer<T>` from [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829#issuecomment-504042546).  All of those are the same general idea: you are trying to prevent the inference of the type parameter from the function parameter, even though such inference is almost always desirable.  Hence why I'm a bit uncomfortable with it.

Comment: One more thing before I answer; how badly do you want to avoid the `oopsieDoodle` situation from [here](https://tsplay.dev/W4yOAw)?  If you care, I can do [this](https://tsplay.dev/NaY1oN) which extends the "no infer" trick to the return type.

Comment: To be honest, I gonna stick to a custom `NoInfer<T>` in my implementation as I want to prevent this "dead" method types. You are free to give multiple possible answers. That being said: I'm pretty much thankful and learned a lot today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's remove the second two type parameters on `Service`, since they don't seem to serve a purpose other than to be a "copy" of the existing request/response body types:

```
class Service<Rq, Rs> { /* ... */ }
```

Note that I'm using `Rq` and `Rs` to represent the original request and response body types, respectively, as I tend to follow the (admittedly had to read sometimes) convention where generic type parameters have short one-or-two character names so they can be distinguished from specific types.

---

So for the `create()` method, what you generally want is for the `body` type to be `Rq` and for the return type to be `Rs`.  But, you'd also like to be able to *override* these types by explicitly specifying types when you call it, like `create<NewRequestType, NewResponseType>(body)`, which would have `body` be of type `NewRequestType` and would return a `NewResponseType`.

Disclaimer: At this point I want to note that it's hard to imagine any implementation of this function which could possibly be type safe, since the implementation at runtime will know nothing about what types were passed in for the compiler.  For example, `create<string, number>("hey")` should return a `number` and `create<string, boolean>("hey")` should return a `boolean`, but both calls compile to the JavaScript `create("hey")`, so there's no way even in principle for this to be accurate in all cases.  It seems like you just want to let callers use these type parameters as if they were using [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions), like `create("hey") as number` or `create("hey") as boolean`, which is at least an explicit and well-known way to acknowledge that you're giving up on type safety.  But in the interest of progress, I'll consider type safety of the implementation out of scope and I won't belabor the point further.

---

So, you want  generic call signature like `<RqO, RsO>(body: RqO) => RsO` where `RqO` and `RsO` are the desired override types, but if you don't specify them they fall back to `Rq` and `Rs` respectively.  But the big roadblock you'll have have is that, if you don't specify type parameters, the compiler will try to [infer them](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#inference).  Whatever you pass in for `body` will cause the compiler to infer that type for `RqO`, since `body` is an *inference site* for `RqO`.  Also, if you happen to call `create()` in a place where the return type has an expected [contextual](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) type, the compiler will infer that type for `RsO`, since the contextual return type is an inference site for `RsO`.  And that's not what you want; you want to *disable* type inference for `RqO` and `RsO`.  It would be nice if you could say that `body` should not be used to infer `RqO` and the contextual return type should not be used to infer `RsO`.

There's no offical way to "turn off" an inference site, but there's a feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#14829](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829) which asks for some way to implement a type function like `NoInfer<T>` which evaluates to `T` eventually but cannot be used to infer `T`.  And luckily, there are some suggestions that work for at least some use cases.  The one I usually use is from [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829#issuecomment-504042546):

```
type NoInfer<T> = [T][T extends any ? 0 : never];
```

In case it matters: here we use the fact that [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) that depend on unspecified generics are *deferred*, so `T extends any ? 0 : never` is not evaluated until after `T` is fixed.  Whatever `T` becomes, `T extends any ? 0 : never` will eventually evaluate as `0`, and `[T][0]` is just `T` (because you are [indexing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into the first element of a single-element [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types)).

And that means we can write `create()` like this:

```
    public create<RqO = Rq, RsO = Rs>(
        body: NoInfer<RqO>
    ): NoInfer<RsO> {
        return null!;
    }
```

We're using [generic parameter defaults](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) of `Rq` and `Rs` for `RqO` and `RsO`, so when the type parameters are not specified and when inference fails (which it definitely will), they will fall back to the defaults.

---

So, let's try it out:

```
const service = new Service<{ foo: string }, string>();
```

First, we will not specify the request and response types, and hopefully the compiler will fall back to the `Rq` and `Rs` types from `service`:

```
const ret = service.create({
    foo: 'test'
}).toUpperCase(); // okay

service.create({
    bar: 'test'    }); // error, {bar:string} is not {foo: string}

const ret2: number = service.create({
    foo: 'test'
}); // error, number is not string
```

Looks good.  Now we *will* specify the types, and hopefully the compiler will use them and not the ones from `service`:

```
const ret3 = service.create<{ bar: string }, number>(
    { bar: "test" }).toFixed(2); // okay

const ret4 = service.create<{ bar: string }, number>(
    { foo: "test" }
); // error, {foo:string} is not {bar: string}

const ret5: string = service.create<{ bar: string }, number>(
    { bar: "test" }
```

Also looks good.  So this is a viable solution.

---

Note that there are other ways to get non-inferential type parameter usages.  You could [add additional type parameters](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829#issuecomment-288902999) instead:

```
        public create<
            RqO = Rq,
            RsO = Rs,
            RqI extends RqO = RqO,
            RsI extends RsO = RsO
        >(body: RqI): RsI {
            return null!;
        }
```

which works because the compiler will use `body` to infer `RqI` (think "implicit" override) and the return type to infer `RsI`, but the constraints are `RqI extends RqO` and `RsI extends RsO` and not vice versa.  So the inferences for `RqI` and `RsI` will not affect `RqO` and `RsO`.  You can verify that this behaves similarly.  I won't go into more detail, but it's an approach that sometimes works when `NoInfer<T>` does not.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDB2EMFsFMGcAdwGNoAIByB7AkqAZtAE6oDeIqFqALgJ7xpa4GEA8AKgHyoC8qA2mwC6A1NAAeVaKAAmsVOFA1UAflQAGVAC5UoaADciggNzlKSADbhYcgMpE9ASxQsASgEcANKhewOwSqT+AZTwAK4ARuZOqEiE0OCSrm4A8jzent6wqbw+HAAUQcHB4ZjSNNqM+ERJyX5FFACUFThVrD61gfXBcVShhKA6oebmAIQmXQC+hahT00iYoLBUqLD2Tmi8ugDuqHaEjs4kqHiYmNpLhA6gAOYzXhdX1-kNJtMA9G86mMsI0EgOeBoj2odDgpgo80Wyx6aVW+3WADpYvFJHkyF0TmdUABySRLbHTCYNBFUTAAVXg9EIAGErNA8i9UB9UJgANbgGjglZrFBIuIJeno+rhcCEbS4uBUAkBIlGJmfIiETCELwkEVih43CaoBxyUDfUiY85US5akBzBZLVA9ABM2lAoUg4SIsJ50D5KMF0wCRpxeKlhMZzMVyq8DqdLt1Xx+Jse5oCzN+-0BwNo9FgXMhVp6AGZXfDeciBSwjurjabbhMw47nYR8t7KKXRdoAET+lszYmkgBiDjE0GkeRtQc+bI58bMluh0CoABZ8wd3UXEk2xStYzc7oMI3WCl0jr625KO1MAiPRIQlSrDadNJrrtqo-rlmrm+uK7MAlnp1QAKzl4FeDhRcPWLVcAM3Ktt1ret91QMtUCPJYT2mc8Q2ve8dT1A1w1rc1pmAxFly9LoEIlfFA1eAJCMLfkV3gt9yKlLc9EwBxpHyIUijI-1pUoWV8ICCAYAQZA0AAUQkQhwAABVFKA5DIBsIUsaxdjdJIvFyZTOi6EIIiiJAYjo6AWB0rp3GydIPHM+p2jSHwbL0uy3GwUQJCkWR0isyynOc4IfDc8RJBkOR7JyLJbIofISjKbR3GwJpMjcrj-IoHo+gGB1hjGKKZh0z96m-bkC2gbQ9kXEtjlvd9gSg1j2K4TZoB2Cr1iq31MPqtiOIZKiiqnFlMHgWAHGgAARU5pHMMroJdIC3VA1FUoxGqmL4ooBK6ZlzFOVkvFOEaxsm0oZqw+Q5sICcihopcTLRPLfXWgqXi5ajFuIlgGukLxvs4vKeMlDbggEt7KFupaSP8wGKMmV6dIhz7wL9IGWJ6-60phgM4deQkQAmIA)